# Complex Linq c# query

Tags: c#, linq

I tried this in LinqPad

I have the following data and linq query which should return only 1 record and 2 images but returns 2 records and 4 images.

I know i have something wrong but don't know what. I am looking for the users details + car details + images fro user: 0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7

It has something to do with the bids as when I delete one of he bids for user (0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7 ) i then get 1 record and 2 images

**TABLES

------**

### TABLE bids

```
id      cardid  bidamount   dateplaced          usedid  

43  83  625 2012-11-05 16:12:51.600 a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc  
44  86  575 2012-11-05 16:15:02.257 a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc  
45  83  650 2012-11-05 16:15:07.283 a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc  
46  86  600 2012-11-05 17:45:04.140 a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc  
47  86  625 2012-11-05 17:45:08.867 a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc  
49  83  750 2012-11-07 13:40:37.590 0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7  
52  83  850 2012-11-08 13:40:37.590 0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7
```

### TABLE userdetails

```
userid                                  city    state  
0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7    Sydney  NSW
```

### TABLE cars

```
id  name     descr   listingOption priceStarting priceReserve  
83  Valiant  Old Car     2              1000         1500  
86  Volvo    Safe Car    3              3000         4500
```

### TABLE auction_images

```
id         image                                              belongs_to  
71  images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/alpaca.JPG  83  
72  images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/a_bag.jpg   83  
75  images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/alpaca.JPG  86  
76  images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/a_bag.jpg   86
```

**QUERY
-----**

```
 var query = (from c in cars
                         from ud in users_details
                         from bd in bids
                         orderby c.listingOption descending
                         where a.userID == ud.userid
                        && c.id == bd.carID
                        && c.enabled == true
                        && bd.userID == new Guid("0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7")
                         let images = from ai in auction_images
                                      where ai.belongs_to == c.id
                                      select ai

                         let bid = (from b in bids
                                    orderby b.id descending
                                    where b.carID == c.id
                                    select b.bidamount).FirstOrDefault()
                         select
                         new
                         {
                             images,
                             bidamount = (bid != null ? bid : 0),
                             ud.city,
                             ud.state,
                             c.name,
                             c.descr,
                             c.id,
                             c.listingOption,
                             c.priceStarting,
                             c.priceReserve,
                             bd.userID
                         }
                         );

query.Distinct().Dump();
```

Comment: ...nor have you cast any votes... ever.

Comment: @spender he'd have to have 15+ rep first though... I agree that he has to pick some answers in his previous questions though.

Comment: @user389391: Since you have two elements on the cars table, you are doing the `select new {...}` twice.

Comment: @steve,

Yes I do apologize for this but I do remember that almost all the suggestions I ever gotten have been wrong or not helped :-( Maybe  I should have commented such but my time is so busy that I end up just carrying on and finding another way often.

I aim to correct my "marking" :-)

Comment: @Tom I am not sure I folow as my intention is to only find the bids for one user and return the details and their last bid

Comment: Is the line 'where a.userID == ud.userid' a typo as 'a' is not defined as any of your tables and this leaves no join from ud to any of the other tables?

Comment: @user389391, see my post it works for you. I found lot of mistakes in your post. some of them are, you wrote in query "c.enabled" but "cars" table doesnot have "enabled" and also many columns names are mismatching. Please do better. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very big home work. Here you go,

Use this query,

```
            var query = from bd in lstbids
                    group bd by new { carid = bd.carid, userid = bd.userid } into gbd
                    join ud in lstuserdetails on gbd.First().userid equals ud.userid
                    join c in lstcars on gbd.First().carid equals c.id
                    where c.enabled && ud.userid == new Guid("0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7")
                    select new
                    {
                        images = lstaction_images.Where(ai => ai.belongs_to == c.id),
                        bidamount = lstbids.Where(b => b.carid == c.id).OrderByDescending(b => b.id).Select(b => b.bidamount).DefaultIfEmpty(0).FirstOrDefault(),
                        ud.city,
                        ud.state,
                        c.name,
                        c.descr,
                        c.id,
                        c.listingOption,
                        c.priceStarting,
                        c.priceReserve,
                        gbd.FirstOrDefault().userid
                    };
```

**Note**: This query can be written in better way.

Here is sample tables (I considered your tables as List for me):

**Tables / Class**

```
public class userdetails
{ 
    public Guid userid { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class bids
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int carid { get; set; }
    public int bidamount { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateplaced { get; set; }
    public Guid userid { get; set; }
}

public class  cars
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
    public int listingOption { get; set; }
    public int priceStarting { get; set; }
    public int priceReserve { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
}

public class action_images
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public int belongs_to { get; set; }
}
```

**Data / Records**

```
        List<bids> lstbids = new List<bids>
        { 
            new bids {id= 43, carid=83, bidamount=625, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-05 16:12:51.600"), userid=new Guid("a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc") }, 
            new bids {id= 44, carid=86, bidamount=575, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-05 16:15:02.257"), userid=new Guid("a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc")  },
            new bids {id= 45, carid=83, bidamount=650, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-05 16:15:07.283"), userid=new Guid("a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc")  },
            new bids {id= 46, carid=86, bidamount=600, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-05 17:45:04.140"), userid=new Guid("a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc")  },
            new bids {id= 47, carid=86, bidamount=625, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-05 17:45:08.867"), userid=new Guid("a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc")  },
            new bids {id= 49, carid=83, bidamount=750, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-07 13:40:37.590"), userid=new Guid("0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7")  },
            new bids {id= 52, carid=83, bidamount=850, dateplaced=Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-08 13:40:37.590"), userid=new Guid("0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7") },
        };

        List<userdetails> lstuserdetails = new List<userdetails>
        {
            new userdetails { userid = new Guid ("0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7"), city = "Sydney", state = "NSW"},
        };

        List<cars> lstcars = new List<cars>
        {
            new cars {id = 83, name = "Valiant", descr = "Old Car", listingOption = 2, priceStarting = 1000, priceReserve = 1500, enabled = true },
            new cars {id = 86, name = "Volvo", descr = "Safe Car", listingOption = 3, priceStarting = 3000, priceReserve = 4500, enabled = true },
        };

        List<action_images> lstaction_images = new List<action_images>
        {
            new action_images { id = 71 , image = "images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/alpaca.JPG", belongs_to =83 },
            new action_images { id = 72 , image = "images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/a_bag.jpg", belongs_to =83 },
            new action_images { id = 75 , image = "images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/alpaca.JPG", belongs_to =86 },
            new action_images { id = 76 , image = "images/a5d383e0-0c2c-44cf-9da1-0ce364b1dbdc/a_bag.jpg", belongs_to =86 },
        };
```

Comment: @user389391 try this query.. it works for you. please let me know.

Comment: Thanks again for a very interesting attempt at solving this but...  

The results return two unqiue bids for user "0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7" when they should only have one unique bid as noted by the data.

Comment: OK scrap my above comments as further testing has revealed you may have it down except it get a an error: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'. If i take it out is seems to work. Testing further and will update you

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for the users details + car details + images fro user:
>   0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7

Judging by what you said in that line, your goals can be acieved by splitting the query into 3 separate and using Distinct function for car IDs.

The course of action is as follows:

1. Find all distinct car IDs from the bid table for current user
2. Find all images (and user/car details) corresponding to the data from step 1

The code would be something like this:

var carIDs = bids.Where(x=>x.usedid == new Guid("0b3c2ba5-1538-4557-a6c0-7de701fd83e7")).Select(x=>x.cardid).Distinct();

Then you can select the user details and images (in two separate queries).

Comment: Thanks I will try your method if Prasads solution does not work as I happen to see his and try it first as it was on top and more in line with what I want as a all in one query :-)